# Aptitude или apt-get upgrade как изменить отображение пакетов?

Tags: debian

Как при обновлении изменить отображение пакетов?

Например, как это сделано в  *yum*.
Чтобы список был в столбик, а не сплошной строкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

получить «в столбик» список пакетов, которые могут быть обновлены (upgradable), можно в несколько разных форматах:

программой *apt*:

```
$ apt list --upgradable 
Listing... Done
apt/stable 1.4.8 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.4.7]
apt-transport-https/stable 1.4.8 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.4.7]
...
```

программой *aptitude*:

```
$ aptitude search '~U'
i   apt                                          - commandline package manager                            
i   apt-transport-https                          - https download transport for APT
...
```

программой *apt-get*

```
$ apt-get --just-print --no-show-upgraded upgrade 
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-headers-amd64 linux-image-amd64
102 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Inst base-files [9.9+deb9u1] (9.9+deb9u2 Debian:stable-updates [amd64])
Conf base-files (9.9+deb9u2 Debian:stable-updates [amd64])
Inst ncurses-bin [6.0+20161126-1] (6.0+20161126-1+deb9u1 Debian:9.2/stable [amd64])
Conf ncurses-bin (6.0+20161126-1+deb9u1 Debian:9.2/stable [amd64])
...
```